# How can I check route scope in a rails view layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in my routes.rb:

```
get "/account" => "main_site/account#index"
scope "/account" do
  resources :driver_sites, :controller=> "main_site/driver_site", :except => :index
end
```

In application.html.erb I have a navigation bar with a set of menu items.  I need to alter one of the menu items only when the controller is 'account' or the scope is "/account" (ie "account/driver_sites/48/edit").  The rest of the layout is identical.

I could manually check for the controller being driver_sites as well, but I'll be adding additional resources under the "/account" scope as well, so a general check for scope being account would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a quirky solution : you can use `Resquest#fullpath` to access the query path part, so this should work:

```
 request.fullpath =~ %r[^/account]
```